# How can I fill down in kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I would like my kusto query to remember and return, i.e. fill-down, the last non-null or non-empty value when I parse or extract a field from a log as below.

```
datatable (Date:datetime, LogEntry:string) [ 
  datetime(1910-06-11), "version: 1.0",
  datetime(1930-01-01), "starting foo",
  datetime(1953-01-01), "ending foo",
  datetime(1910-06-11), "version: 2.0",
  datetime(1930-01-01), "starting foo",
  datetime(1953-01-01), "ending foo" ]
| parse LogEntry with 'version: ' Version
| project Date, Version, LogEntry
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Greg - Can you please provide a more elaborate example (using datatable() for the data and the expected output)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, are you looking for something like this:

```
let sampleData = datatable (Date:datetime, LogEntry:string) [ 
  datetime(1910-06-11), "version: 1.1",
  datetime(1930-01-01), "starting foo",
  datetime(1953-01-01), "ending foo",
  datetime(1910-06-11), "version: 2.1",
  datetime(1930-01-01), "starting foo",
  datetime(1953-01-01), "ending foo",
  datetime(1950-01-01), "version: 3.1"]
| parse LogEntry with 'version: ' Version:double
| order by Date asc
| extend rn = row_number()
| extend rn = iif(isempty(Version),0 , rn)
| extend rn = row_cumsum(rn, rn!=0);
sampleData
| project-away Version
| lookup (sampleData | where isnotempty(Version) ) on rn
| project-away Date1, LogEntry1, rn
```

here is the output:

[image]